# Any recommendations for a Web based Daily Schedule event control Toolkit

Tags: user-interface, calendar, widget, schedule

We have a backend VB based scheduling app which we would like to ***webify***.  A key function point is displaying multi-person schedule (with possible multi-events) for a selected day.

A sample can be seen at  http://flic.kr/p/8rT4aR

In VB we've used a **non-web** custom control **SchedOCX** to deliver this functionality.

Any recommendation for an HTML5/SVG toolkit which might reduce they effort in replicating this control?

*Bonus points if this functionality can be driven from a Ruby/Rails infrastructure :-)*

Any/all assistance appreciated... Thanks

Comment: We ended update resorting to generating a javascript "control" based on HTML5 Canvas.  It was fairly painless and the EXCANVAS emulation have us the necessary cross-browser support we needed (works in Firefox, Safari, and IE6 and up)

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik RadScheduler is an option for such scheduling apps.  I have implemented one as a POC, but did not attempt many customizations, which there are a few.

Comment: Thanks for the lead... Looks like a capable toolkit.  I was hoping for an open source solution since I've been *burned* once with the disappearance of the SchedOCX supplier.

Answer (score 0):

As websch01ar has mentioned, the Telerik RadScheduler is indeed a control that can be used in this scenario. If you are concerned about having access to the source code, I'm happy to say that the source code to RadScheduler, and all other RadControls, is available as part of the control package.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... I wonder if they can be easily accessed from Ruby/Rails.